# FXM + xDB. Analytics goes to the wrong contact

Tags: xdb, fxm

I'm having a strange issue with FXM + Analytics. We use Sitecore 8.1 + FXM + xDB.
We noticed that analytics for the FXM sites is collected against a different contact.
For example, a request from external site to track page event is recorded against wrong contact and not the one specified in the url parameters:

```
[https://server.com]/sitecore/api/ssc/Beacon/Service/beacon/trackPageVisit/?contactId=[contact_guid]|True&sessionId=[session_guid]&page=[https://ext.server.com/]&referrer=[https://server.com/]&rt=1509488103273
```

In the xDB device collection, there is an entry that has correct contact id as `_id` and wrong contact id as `LastKnownContactId`. Not sure, how that happened, maybe during testing testers didn't clean up the cookies and logged in with these two users.

Apparently, Sitecore tries to identify this beacon request and matches it with the wrong contact using devices. And ignoring `contactId` from Url records page visit event for this wrongly identified contact.

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just want to answer my own question. It turned out to be a bug in Sitecore code, please ask Sitecore Support for a package: Sitecore.Support.146899